# StencilJS component not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, stenciljs

I can't get some StencilJS components to run in Firefox. The page is returning the following message.

```
This Stencil app is disabled for this browser.
```

Developers:

```
ES5 builds are disabled during development to take advantage of 2x faster build times.
Please see the example below or our config docs if you would like to develop on a browser that does not fully support ES2017 and custom elements.
Note that by default, ES5 builds and polyfills are enabled during production builds.
When testing browsers it is recommended to always test in production mode, and ES5 builds should always be enabled during production builds.
This is only an experiement and if it slows down app development then we will revert this and enable ES5 builds during dev.
```

Enabling ES5 builds during development:

```
npm run dev --es5
```

For stencil-component-starter, use:

```
npm start --es5
```

Enabling full production builds during development:

```
npm run dev --prod
```

For stencil-component-starter, use:

```
npm start --prod
```

Current Browser's Support:

```
ES Module Imports: true
ES Dynamic Imports: false
Custom Elements: false
Shadow DOM: false
fetch: true
CSS Variables: true
```

Current Browser:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
```

What I tried:

```
- Turned on the `customEmements` web component in `about:config`
- Ran Stencil with npm start --prod
```

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Edit:

When running with `npm start --es5` I get the following error only in Firefox

```
ReferenceError
​
columnNumber: 1612
​
fileName: "http://localhost:3333/build/community-component/chunk-9a3c139c.es5.js"
​
lineNumber: 761
​
message: "module is not defined"
```

Lines 760 - 762 from `chunk-9a3c139c.es5.js`

```
catch (e) { } t = "ibm-cxtype-" + t, e(document.documentElement).addClass("js ibm-v18 " + t), Modernizr.addTest("hires", function () { return 1 < (window.devicePixelRatio || window.screen.deviceXDPI / window.screen.logicalXDPI || 1); }); }(jQuery), function (r) { r.browserTest = function (e, t) { var a = "unknown", s = function (e, t) { for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i += 1)
        e = e.replace(t[i][0], t[i][1]); return e; }, i = function (e, t, i, n) { var o = { name: s((t.exec(e) || [a, a])[1], i) }; return o[o.name] = !0, o.version = (n.exec(e) || ["X", "X", "X", "X"])[3], o.name.match(/safari/) && 400 < o.version && (o.version = "2.0"), "presto" === o.name && (o.version = 9.27 < r.browser.version ? "futhark" : "linear_b"), o.versionNumber = parseFloat(o.version, 10) || 0, o.versionX = "X" !== o.version ? (o.version + "").substr(0, 1) : "X", o.className = o.name + o.versionX, o; }; e = (e.match(/Opera|Navigator|Minefield|KHTML|Chrome/) ? s(e, [[/(Firefox|MSIE|KHTML,\slike\sGecko|Konqueror)/, ""], ["Chrome Safari", "Chrome"], ["KHTML", "Konqueror"], ["Minefield", "Firefox"], ["Navigator", "Netscape"]]) : e).toLowerCase(), r.browser = r.extend(t ? {} : r.browser, i(e, /(camino|chrome|firefox|netscape|konqueror|lynx|msie|opera|safari)/, [], /(camino|chrome|firefox|netscape|netscape6|opera|version|konqueror|lynx|msie|safari)(\/|\s)([a-z0-9\.\+]*?)(\;|dev|rel|\s|$)/)), r.layout = i(e, /(gecko|konqueror|msie|opera|webkit)/, [["konqueror", "khtml"], ["msie", "trident"], ["opera", "presto"]], /(applewebkit|rv|konqueror|msie)(\:|\/|\s)([a-z0-9\.]*?)(\;|\)|\s)/), r.os = { name: (/(win|mac|linux|sunos|solaris|iphone)/.exec(navigator.platform.toLowerCase()) || [a])[0].replace("sunos", "solaris") }, t || r("html").addClass([r.os.name, r.browser.name, r.browser.className, r.layout.name, r.layout.className].join(" ")); }, r.browserTest(navigator.userAgent); }(jQuery), function (e) { "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["jquery"], e) : "undefined" != typeof exports ? module.exports = e(require("jquery")) : e(jQuery); }(function (c) { var o, s = window.Slick || {}; o = 0, (s = function (e, t) { var i, n = this; n.defaults = { accessibility: !0, adaptiveHeight: !1, appendArrows: c(e), appendDots: c(e), arrows: !0, asNavFor: null, prevArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-prev" aria-label="Previous" tabindex="0" role="button">Previous</button>', nextArrow: '<button type="button" data-role="none" class="slick-next" aria-label="Next" tabindex="0" role="button">Next</button>', autoplay: !1, autoplaySpeed: 3e3, centerMode: !1, centerPadding: "50px", cssEase: "ease", customPaging: function (e, t) { return c('<button type="button" data-role="none" role="button" tabindex="0" />').text(t + 1); }, dots: !1, dotsClass: "slick-dots", draggable: !0, easing: "linear", edgeFriction: .35, fade: !1, focusOnSelect: !1, infinite: !0, initialSlide: 0, lazyLoad: "ondemand", mobileFirst: !1, pauseOnHover: !0, pauseOnFocus: !0, pauseOnDotsHover: !1, respondTo: "window", responsive: null, rows: 1, rtl: !1, slide: "", slidesPerRow: 1, slidesToShow: 1, slidesToScroll: 1, speed: 500, swipe: !0, swipeToSlide: !1, touchMove: !0, touchThreshold: 5, useCSS: !0, useTransform: !0, variableWidth: !1, vertical: !1, verticalSwiping: !1, waitForAnimate: !0, zIndex: 1e3 }, n.initials = { animating: !1, dragging: !1, autoPlayTimer: null, currentDirection: 0, currentLeft: null, currentSlide: 0, direction: 1, $dots: null, listWidth: null, listHeight: null, loadIndex: 0, $nextArrow: null, $prevArrow: null, slideCount: null, slideWidth: null, $slideTrack: null, $slides: null, sliding: !1, slideOffset: 0, swipeLeft: null, $list: null, touchObject: {}, transformsEnabled: !1, unslicked: !1 }, c.extend(n, n.initials), n.activeBreakpoint = null, n.animType = null, n.animProp = null, n.breakpoints = [], n.breakpointSettings = [], n.cssTransitions = !1, n.focussed = !1, n.interrupted = !1, n.hidden = "hidden", n.paused = !0, n.positionProp = null, n.respondTo = null, n.rowCount = 1, n.shouldClick = !0, n.$slider = c(e), n.$slidesCache = null, n.transformType = null, n.transitionType = null, n.visibilityChange = "visibilitychange", n.windowWidth = 0, n.windowTimer = null, i = c(e).data("slick") || {}, n.options = c.extend({}, n.defaults, t, i), n.currentSlide = n.options.initialSlide, n.originalSettings = n.options, void 0 !== document.mozHidden ? (n.hidden = "mozHidden", n.visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange") : void 0 !== document.webkitHidden && (n.hidden = "webkitHidden", n.visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange"), n.autoPlay = c.proxy(n.autoPlay, n), n.autoPlayClear = c.proxy(n.autoPlayClear, n), n.autoPlayIterator = c.proxy(n.autoPlayIterator, n), n.changeSlide = c.proxy(n.changeSlide, n), n.clickHandler = c.proxy(n.clickHandler, n), n.selectHandler = c.proxy(n.selectHandler, n), n.setPosition = c.proxy(n.setPosition, n), n.swipeHandler = c.proxy(n.swipeHandler, n), n.dragHandler = c.proxy(n.dragHandler, n), n.keyHandler = c.proxy(n.keyHandler, n), n.instanceUid = o++, n.htmlExpr = /^(?:\s*(<[\w\W]+>)[^>]*)$/, n.registerBreakpoints(), n.init(!0); }).prototype.activateADA = function () { this.$slideTrack.find(".slick-active").attr({ "aria-hidden": "false" }).find("a, input, button, select").attr({ tabindex: "0" }); }, s.prototype.addSlide = s.prototype.slickAdd = function (e, t, i) { var n = this; if ("boolean" == typeof t)
        i = t, t = null;
```

Comment: The solution is right there -  `npm run dev --es5` or `npm start --es5`. In other words, you have to specifically enable es5 support when you are not in production.

Comment: Sorry ... forgot to mention it. Tried and I get  an error. See my edit please.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of `chunk-9a3c139c.es5.js` (only the lines around 761).

Comment: See my edit please. It seems to be from `module.exports = e(require("jquery")) : e(jQuery)`

Comment: Which version of Stencil are you using? Can you update to `0.18.0` to see if that fixes the problem? (AFAIK there are some bugs in `0.18.1`)

Comment: I got it to work ... using `npm start --es5`,  I also had a conf file which I wanted to import into each component. Seems it didn't like that. I copied the code to each component for now. So how do I build and deply to npm with the `--es5` support. Without that it still doesn't run in Firefox. Thanks @Thomas I was using version 0.15

Comment: "Note that by default, ES5 builds and polyfills are enabled during production builds." `--prod`